# Question about Solr and SolrJ range query?

Tags: solr

Suppose that my index has 3 fields: title, x and y.

I know one range(10 < x < 100) can query like this:

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=x:[10 TO 100]&fl=title

If I want to two range(10 < x <100 AND 20 < y < 300) query like

SQL(select title where x>10 and x < 100 and y > 20 and y < 300)

by using Solr range query or SolrJ, but I don't know how to implement this. Does anybody else know? Thanks

Email: enzhaohoo@gmail.com

Comment: Why is this community wiki? Does not look like a discussion kind of thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html) for SolrJ.  Successive calls to addFilterQuery will continue to build up your query.  Alternatively you can have two things in one fq:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=&fq=x:[10+TO+100]+AND+y:[20+TO+300]&fl=title
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in class SolrQuery can solve your problem,
setFilterQueries(String... fq)
You can take a look at this.